# Вопрос про ajax в wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть вот такой аякс запрос

```
$("#lostfound").submit(function() {
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $('.error_block').html(data);
            /*if(data == 'success'){
                window.location.href = "<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/lost-found/";
            }*/
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

    return false;
});
```

Как мне добавить `{action: 'name'};` в `formData`?

Comment: `formData.append('action', 'name');` пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал вот так )) formData.append('{action: "send_data"}'); спасибо!